# Error when trying to run a simple script with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to Selenium and just trying to open a browser with it, but it's giving me a tough time. Whenever I try to run the below code it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Syntax error on token "void", @ expected
Syntax error on token "]", :: expected after this token
Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete EnumHeader
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete EnumBody

at TestClass1.main(TestClass1.java:7)
```

I have tried quite a lot of stuff but couldn't find any thing.

```
public class TestClass1{

    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "c:\\path\\to\\firefox.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("www.google.com");
        driver.quit();
    }}

}
```

Comment: Why are your imports inside your class body?

Comment: When you said that you tried a lot of stuff — what did you find out when you Googled the error that you're getting?

Comment: Hey Hexafraction thanks a ton for your help it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Place your imports outside your class and try using http:// in your url -

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class TestClass1{

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    driver.quit();
  }
}
```